# cat files in current folder and all subfolders

Tags: shell, directory, cat, tree

I want to `cat` a file in current folder and all files in all subfolders (and subsubfolders).

Here is my directory structure

```
$ tree
.
├── f
│   └── foo
└── yo
```

I want to cat `foo` and `yo`.

I've tried this command but did not work:

```
cat */*
```

It just `cat`s `foo`.

Comment: Dup. http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76418/6622 You search before asking

Comment: Super dangerous to do this because the files may contain commands. You should always run a `file` on the file first

Answer (score 63, accepted):

try:

```
   find . -type f -exec cat {} +
```

Comment: What's the `+` for?  I used to end these type of commands with `\;`.

Comment: @StephenRasku - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085156/using-semicolon-vs-plus-with-exec-in-find

Comment: `-exec foo {} \;` is `foo x; foo y; foo z;`, but `-exec foo {} +` is `foo x y z`.

Answer (score 24):

cat accepts multiple arguments, so you can:

```
  cat * */*
```

to cat everything in the current directory and in all subdirectories.  You can also

```
  cat * */* */*/*
```

and so on, if you want.

Note, of course, that your shell is translating those '*'s into a list of files then passing that whole list to cat.

Comment: With `shopt -s globstar` enabled on bash 4+, you can use `cat **` instead of the second one.

Comment: That's not a useful solution, as you need to know how many layers deep to go.

Comment: Moreover, the directories will be processed